# MetaTransactions - MinimalForwarder and Web3j

Tags: openzeppelin, web3j, meta-transactions

I'm trying to sign a smart contract function with UserA and send the transaction to the Blockchain with UserB, using web3j.

I've tried with web3js and everything worked fine, following the example of [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/defender-example-metatx-relay)

I'd like to do the same with java and web3j, but I'm not able to make it work.

Both following contracts have been wrapped to a java classes, deployed locally (i'm using a dockerized ganache), and I can interact with them: Greeting and MinimalForwarder.

The problems come when I try to execute the function "execute" of the MinimalForwarder. Here's the code:

```
public TransactionReceipt emitRegistry(Web3j web3j, String signerPrivateKey, String senderPrivateKey, String registryContractAddress, String forwardContractAddress, String addressToSendGreetingsTo) throws Exception {
    final Credentials signerCredentials = Credentials.create(signerPrivateKey);
    final Credentials senderCredentials = Credentials.create(senderPrivateKey);

    BigInteger gasPrice = web3j.ethGasPrice().send().getGasPrice();
    BigInteger gasLimit = DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT;

    final Function createRegistryfunction = new Function(
            FUNC_CREATEREGISTRY,
            List.of(new Address(160, addressToSendGreetingsTo)),
            Collections.emptyList());
    byte[] encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(createRegistryfunction).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // Send the signed transaction to the network
    Sign.SignatureData signature = Sign.signMessage(encodedFunction, signerCredentials.getEcKeyPair());
    byte[] signatureInBytes = new byte[65];
    System.arraycopy(signature.getR(), 0, signatureInBytes, 0, 32);
    System.arraycopy(signature.getS(), 0, signatureInBytes, 32, 32);
    System.arraycopy(signature.getV(), 0, signatureInBytes, 64, 1);

    MinimalForwarder minimalForwarder = MinimalForwarder.load(forwardContractAddress, web3j, senderCredentials, new DefaultGasProvider());
    BigInteger nonce = minimalForwarder.getNonce(signerCredentials.getAddress()).send();

    // create forward request
    MinimalForwarder.ForwardRequest forwardRequest = new MinimalForwarder.ForwardRequest(
            signerCredentials.getAddress(),
            registryContractAddress,
            BigInteger.ZERO,
            gasLimit,
            nonce,
            encodedFunction
    );

    return minimalForwarder.execute(forwardRequest, signatureInBytes, gasLimit.add(gasPrice)).send();
}
```

I keep receiving the message "MinimalForwarder: signature does not match request". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, the implementation can be seen here: https://docs.web3j.io/4.10.0/use_cases/meta_transaction/

Together with the author of the article we've been able to figure it out